# Subscriber and publisher in one file in ROS

Tags: c++, ros

How to make a subscriber and publisher in ROS on C++ in one file? I tried this and publisher works but subscriber callback function is not called

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <math.h>

int error = 0;

void error_sub(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg)
 {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", msg->data);
    error = msg->data;
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "lighter");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Publisher connected =nh.advertise<std_msgs::UInt16>("/robot/sonar/head_sonar/lights/set_lights",1);

    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/plc/error", 1000, error_sub);
    std_msgs::UInt16 msg;

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        if(error >= 0)
        {
            msg.data = 36863;
            connected.publish(msg);
        }
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have messages incoming in the `"/plc/error"` topic. you can check that using `rostopic echo "/plc/error"`. this should work otherwise !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I does not work because of the bad type of the message. It should be `Int8` instead of `UInt16` in callback function.